# Dragging cells with formulas keeping same sequence logic

Tags: excel

I have some value in cell a1 and these formulas in other cells:

in cell a2: `=$a$1+1`

in cell a3: `=$a$1+2`

in cell a4: `=$a$1+3`

when I select cells a2:a4 and drag down until cell a7 in order to fill the formulas with continuation of the same logic, I get same formulas:

in cell a5: `=$a$1+1`

in cell a6: `=$a$1+2`

in cell a7: `=$a$1+3`

Instead of:

in cell a5: `=$a$1+4`

in cell a6: `=$a$1+5`

in cell a7: `=$a$1+6`

Is there a way to achieve this result by dragging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in A2:

```
=$A$1+Row(1:1)
```

Now as you drag down the Row(1:1) will change to Row(2:2),Row(3:3) and so forth.  Thus adding the needed number.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample may have been over-simplified but this should work in A2.

```
=$A1+1
```

Dragged down it will result in,

```
=$A2+1
=$A3+1
(etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the formulae as well. Since what you want is basically an increasing series by 1, under your cell `A1`; enter your value in A1 (e.g. `2.3618`), and hold the `Ctrl` button on your PC (not sure about Mac), and drag the bottom right corner of the cell `A1` downwards as far as you want. (Also known as Fill Series)

PS: This doesn't work if `A1` has irrational numbers (like `sqrt(2)`, `pi()`, etc.)